# Button not working in Firefox but does in Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, jsx

I am working on a ReactJS application that I made. Here's the [deployed version](https://cotdv2048.herokuapp.com/cotd) to get a better idea of the problem.

The Login button is not working in Firefox in the `Inventory Login` section. Rendered HTML shows it as a button, with a listener on it. Hence it should be working.

Consulting various answers and solutions on StackOverflow regarding buttons in Firefox especially when using JSX have yielded no results. I am pretty sure this doesn't count as interactive content and could still be considered as phrasing as listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233447/what-is-the-difference-between-phrasing-content-and-flow-content).

Here's the code snippet that Inventory Login runs on.

```
import React from "react";

const Login = props => (
  <nav className="login">
    <h2>Inventory Login</h2>
    <p>Sign in to manage your store's inventory.</p>

    <button className="github" onClick={() => props.authenticate()}>
      Log In With GitHub
    </button>
  </nav>
);

export default Login;
```

`props.authenticate()` is calling a function back in App.js that handles authentication through Firebase. I already verified that it was working on Chrome and the prop is being passed through.

What is unique is - another button `ORDER RESET` is working in a 
different component but has almost similar code.

Here's the entire source code - https://github.com/vipulgupta2048/react-cotd

Comment: any error message from firefox console?

Comment: I did a quick check, and it looks like  `transform-style: preserve-3d;` is the thing to blame. Notice that when you try to pick an element with Ctrl+Shift+C in FF devtools inspector, you can't pick a button, it allows only to pick container div. I'd suggest to come up with static HTML layout and reask a question, because this is primarily HTML/CSS problem.

Comment: @estus YES, I did notice that. Didn't understand why it was doing that. Thanks for the help, I will try to implement your advice.

Comment: @Abestrad Nope, I checked that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the CSS property `rotateY(10deg)` in `.catch-of-the-day > :last-child` is making the button non-clickable on Firefox.

Comment: Yes!! That did the trick, but how did you debug this. I am really interested in, how you thought to solve it? 
Also, I need to work on my CSS.